# Check for duplication before insert data into DB table

Tags: php, laravel

I am having little trouble about checking the DB in Laravel. I have scraped data and inserting those into DB. But before inserting progress. I want to check are there any same data or not (for example same url). If there is same url. Then avoid inserting that data.

what I have done so far is right below.

```
$i = 0;
$database = [];
foreach($placeUrls as $k => $urls) {
    $database = [
        "place_id" => $k,
        "website" => "a-site",
        "place_name" => $names[$k],
        "url" => $urls,
    ];

    if ($plan = Plan::where("url", "=", $urls)->first()) {
        if ($plan->url != $database["url"]) {
            $this->line("plan inserted");
            Plan::insertGetId($database);
        }
    }

    $i++;
}
```

But the checking part is not correct. How can I fix it?

Comment: Is `$urls` an array?

Comment: yes it's an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `$urls` is an array. So, let's modify the code a bit.

```
$i = 0;
$database = [];

foreach($placeUrls as $k => $urls) {
    $database = [
        "place_id" => $k,
        "website" => "a-site",
        "place_name" => $names[$k],
        "url" => $urls,
    ];

    if ( ! $plan = Plan::whereIn("url", $urls)->first())
    { // ^              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        if ($plan->url != $database["url"])
        {
            $this->line("plan inserted");
            Plan::insertGetId($database);
        }
    }

    $i++;
}
```

The important thing is the first conditional, it says that if there **is not** a plan with a url included in the `$url` it will enter the conditional. Because, you want to avoid a duplicated entry.

Answer (score 1):

Scrapers and crawlers are very resources-consuming applications, so I prefer to avoid that extra DB select interaction that checks for the same URL before I insert it.

In my simple crawler I added a column to the `URLs` table that holds the URL **hash** and added `UNIQUE` index on that column.

```
ALTER TABLE urls ADD COLUMN url_hash char(32) NOT NULL UNIQUE
```

you can hash the url with something fast like `MD5` algorithm that takes the

```
$hash = md5($method . $domain . $url);
```

you can go with [this option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330799/mysql-get-hash-value-for-each-row) too for hashing

That will allow you to insert every URL you collect, without selecting it first from the database, and let the database deal with the uniqueness problem at a lower level.

*WARNING: don't change the way you create the hash in the future or you will end with many duplicate urls*

Answer (score 0):

you can use if empty

```
$plan = Plan::where("url", "=", $urls)->first()
  if (empty($plan->id)) {
     $this->line("plan inserted");
     Plan::insertGetId($database);
  }
```

or else you can use request validation

```
'url' => 'unique:plan'
```

Comment: actually, trying to check on urls. because next if I scrape data. I don't want to insert same url's data into DB. to prevent that, want to check url is already inside db or not.